# Is it possible to open installed apps using python without using the file path?

Tags: python

I need a quick, smart way to open apps on my windows 11.
I am trying to open installed applications without using the app's file path, I have tried using the Appopener, winsapps, windowapp modules, but I'm having problems with them.

I am using Anaconda Jupyter notebook.

This is the code for AppOpener:

```
from AppOpener import open
open("calculator")
```

The error:
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 from AppOpener import open
2 open("calculator")
IndexError: list index out of range

I am so lost.
I am also open to try anything that helps achieve my goal.
Anything at all!!!

Comment: https://github.com/athrvvvv/AppOpener/issues/10

Answer (score 1):

here is the author of module.

**AppOpener v1.7 released today!!**

You may Upgrade to **AppOpener v1.7** like:

```
pip install AppOpener==1.7
```

I have added an Exception, if the File creation process failed, it will create files using the old method in AppOpener v1.3
Hope soo, this works!!

**If the issue still exists, you may install AppOpener v1.3**

If even things are bad, open an new issue in the AppOpener github [repository.](https://github.com/athrvvvv/AppOpener)

Lots of love,
athrv ❤️

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, but not really. The way commands work on all operating systems is that you have a global `PATH` which tells the command line where to look for commands.

If the path to the exe you want to open is in `PATH` then you can open it in Python (or any other application) without the full path.

So your options are to update your system `PATH` or just use the full file path.

Comment: sorry but can you show me an example/sample of what you mean